# Show the linear span of the given collection is dense in the space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation

> Show that space generated by $\{1, \sin x, \sin 2x, \ldots \sin nx,\ldots\}$ is dense in $C([0,\pi])$.

I am having trouble to show it algebra and get explicit function that separates end points.
After all this is okay. I am curious if it true though.

Comment: `and get explicit function that separates end points` That pretty much kills it before the race begins.

Comment: since sin$nx$ for all n vanishes at both ends then how could it separates those points. I am really confused, could you please elaborate it little bit. And is it Algebra?

Comment: Every function in the given set has $f(0) = f(\pi)$. Therefore that also holds for every function in the generated subspace. Thus the span is not dense. It is dense, however, in the subspace $C_p([0,\pi]) = \{ f \in C([0,\pi]) : f(0) = f(\pi)\}$ of functions that have period $\pi$.

Comment: @ Daniel yes i agree with this argument, but is it algebra? Trig identity of $sin(nx).sin(mx)$ comes in cosine term, which i feel difficult to change in term of $sin(kx)$, $k$ integer

Comment: It's not an algebra, you can't represent e.g. $\sin^2 x$ as a linear combination of $1$ and $\sin (kx)$.

Comment: @ Daniel, exactly! I have similar another confusion, is it true that span of sin$nx$,cos$nx$,$n\ge 0$ approximate any continuous function of $2\pi$ period. Only the question does it separates all points?

Comment: Yes, that system has a dense span. Fejér proved that the arithmetic means of the Fourier series converge uniformly for every continuous $2\pi$-periodic function. Consequently, all points except $0$ and $2\pi$ are separated by some function of the system. In fact, one of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ already separates the points.